# C++ Segmentation fault: 11, trying to overload operator <<

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I'm trying to overload the << operator in this class but this is the output:

```
Hello, 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is my code:

test.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    MYString s("Hello");

    MYString s2;

    string hello = "Hello";

    cout << s.text << ", " << s2.text << endl;

    cout << "S: " << s << endl;

    hello[0] = 'M';
    cout << hello << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is class.h:

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MYString {
public:
    string text;

    MYString(string data="") {
        text = data;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const MYString& data) {
        os << data;
        return(os);
    }
 };


#endif
```

It compiles fine but I have no idea why it says "Segmentation fault: 11". I have no idea what that means either. Could someone tell me how to fix this? And I'm also really new to C++

(And also I know this code is really pointless but I'm just trying to learn stuff and getting used to C++)

Comment: Avoid using `using namespace std;` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) for example on why its bad. And **never** use it in a header file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const MYString& data) {
    os << data; // calls 'ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const MYstring&)' -- oops
    return(os);
}
```

Infinite recursion. Use `os << data.text` instead:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const MYString& data) {
    os << data.text;
    return(os);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you understand *why* this worked and what the difference between your code and the corrected version Zeta showed you is.

Answer (score 8):

You have a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Your `operator<<` calls `operator<<` (same function with same data).

Comment: +1: Actually your link should point to your answer. That would be a perfect example for recursion :D.

Comment: I'm surprised that his compiler didn't tag this as infinite recursion. Mine did: "`warning C4717: 'operator<<' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow`"

Comment: @NikBougalis: Probably GCC, [as it doesn't provide any warning option for possible recursive calls](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).

Comment: Right - but I'm surprised that `gcc` wouldn't provide this functionality - at least in cases like these, that scream bloody murder.

Comment: There is no need to declare your operator `friend`. First of all your members are all public and secondly a member function has access to the class members. The operator method should also be declared to be const `std::ostream& operator<<(...) const`

Comment: @Zeta You can certainly define it as a non friend function.

Comment: @Zeta: I think I was a bit hasty in my comment. I was confused by the function being declared and defined as a friend in the class at the same time. It would be clear to have the `operator<<` function defined outside the class. But it does not need to be a `friend` if all members can be accessed either through getters or by the virtue of them being public.

Comment: @AxelOmega: True, I was also a bit hasty in my comment, it was a long day. Yes, `friend` is completely unnecessary if the members are public or accessible with getters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to:

```
os << data.text;
```

in your overloaded operator, lest you be caught in an infinite recursion. What you currently have will just keep calling itself continuously until your stack blows up.

---

As an aside, I'm not a big fan of `return(os)`, it makes it look like a function call which it definitely isn't. You can simply do `return os`, even for very complicated expressions.

And at some point, you will end up having the epiphany that data members should almost always be private, that's what encapsulation is all about. Without that, C++ would just be a harder-to-learn C :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to output the string contained into your `MyString` object, so you should replace

```
os << data;
```

with

```
os << data.text;
```

This is the whole point of having a `friend` function.

As it is, you do an infinite recursion because `os << data;` calls itself the `<<` operator of your function (`data` is of type `MyString`)

Answer (score 0):

You should change os << data to os << data.text